# Tab events not showing on website, from Facebook API

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am embedding a Facebook events feed through their API to my website (I have a developer account and I am logged into it), however after using the Facebook plugin part https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/# and selecting the event tab, it just shows a header of the page, and nothing else: (Result of the problem here: https://www.hairydogvenue.co.uk/gig-guide )

Is this just a bug on Facebook's side? It was working fine for many months before, I am also an admin of the page in question.

iframe code here:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fthehairydogderby&tabs=events&width=500&height=850&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=505386827636891" width="500" height="850" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

Comment: Yes it is a Facebook bug

Comment: same issue here , any solution found?

Comment: Yes, this is happening for me too. It used to be working, but it stopped working at some point recently.

Comment: It's still broken in March 2022

Comment: The bug is open in fb support forum: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/314594194066745/

Comment: As of May it isn't fixed yet... I guess they're running out of budget at Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it worked for me.
If you remove
data-tabs="events"

and replace it with
data-show-posts="true"

Doesn't make sense, but works.

Comment: I don't see `data-tabs` as an attribute of `<iframe>` in the original question. Are you suggesting the solution is something like `<iframe data-show-posts="true" ...>`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).