# Facebook page plugin not showing events

Tags: facebook, plugins

I have put this code right after my body tag using this [fb plugin page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v19.0" nonce="dRrcwaHH"></script>
```

and then this into my page

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/daddythosemenscareme" data-tabs="timeline, events" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/daddythosemenscareme" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/daddythosemenscareme">Daddy Those Men Scare Me</a></blockquote></div>
```

The timeline tab shows but the events tab is blank. Also I have asked it to show faces and it isn't. Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70379389/tab-events-not-showing-on-website-from-facebook-api) suggest there is a bug ... but this is from 2 years ago. I have posted on the fb support - no reply (obv)

Any ideas?